# Improve qps for postgres write

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I am trying to improve the performance of my `postgres` instance in aws.

I am using `aws` `rds` `db.t2.large`

Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_test

(
    test_index1 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    test_index2 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    json_dump json,
    time_stamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    meta_info text,
    CONSTRAINT my_test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (test_index1, test_index2)

)
WITH (OIDS = FALSE)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The current time for taking to do the following operation is about `0.02 - 0.08` seconds

```
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM my_test \
        WHERE test_index1 = %s and test_index2 = %s", \
        (my_index1, my_index2,))

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_test ( \
            test_index1, \
            test_index2, \
            json_dump, \
            time_stamp \
            )  \
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (my_index1_1,
         my_index2_2,
         json.dumps(some_json), 
         "now()", )
    )
```

Each JSON dump less than `500kb`

This code exists in the `ec2` that is the same zone of my `rds`

When I load test it I load test with 30k rows and perform reads and write.

I am only using 1 out of 20GB of space and 1 out of 4GB worth of memory.

My CPU utilization is low for both ec2 and rds eg. 10% or less

I am not entirely sure if this is normal, but I want to achieve 100 writes per second but right now it is sub 20.

I also try to upgrade my rds but the qps did not improve

Can someone point me a direction of how to debug this, like is there some network setting or memory setting I can check that is bottlenecking in ec2 or rds?

Comment: Yes they are primary key `PRIMARY KEY (test_index1, test_index2)`

Comment: my `select` are using those index, but I am mainly testing write for now. Since the table is so simple and I am only testing 30k rows of data, I feel that I must be doing some other config incorrect, but I will check the execution plan

Comment: oh no, each delete and insert is 1 row., however the average qps is around 10 to 20. What i meant is that I construct a db that have 30k rows of data and do insert and delete on top of that to see the performance